# How can a website prevent Similarweb from detecting its technology?

Tags: alexa

How does Similarweb and Alexa detect a websites technology or framework used? What are the ways to disable those so such information is not public.

Comment: See also: [How To Hide From BuiltWith?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32023/how-to-hide-from-builtwith)